# Limiting text column characters in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I have a Laravel 5 application, and I am trying to limit the length of a database `TEXT` column up to 500.

I have it set as:

```php
$table->text('excerpt');
```

How can I modify this so that it is limited to 500 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Require Doctrine:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Create a new migration using string() instead of text():

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('excerpt', 500)->change();
    });
}
```

Or you can use raw SQL:

```php
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY excerpt VARCHAR(500)');
}
```

And run the migrate command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Why use string instead of text, I thought string had a limit of 255?

Comment: @fightstarr20 That's ancient info. MySQL 5.0.3 raised it to 65,535. Postgres's limit is about a gigabyte. 500 will be just fine.